# Automatic Nested Object Creation on Compound Assignment

Tags: javascript

I felt like this ought to be a common requirement and that, surely, there would be a facility which currently exists as part of some well used javascript library (like underscore.js) but my searching has been in vain.

Does anyone know of any library which offers this facility? I am not interested in homegrown solutions - I know it can be done and know how to implement a simplified version of it.

I wanted to be able to do something like the following assignment automatically creating the referenced nested objects:

```
a.b.c = 'Hello World';
```

Essentially the equivalent of:

```
a = {};
a.b = {};
a.b.c = 'Hello World';
```

or

```
a = {b: {c: 'Hello World'}}
```

The library function might look like:

```
a = createAndSet('b.c', 'Hello World');
```

A more complicated example

```
a = createAndSet('b[2].c['thing'][1]', 'Hello World');
```

which would be the equivalent of:

```
a = {
  b: [
    undefined, 
    undefined,
    {
      c: {
        thing: [
          undefined,
          'Hello World'
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

After creation you would be able to read the string value 'Hello World' like so:

```
b[2].c['thing'][1]
```

Thanks

Comment: No, such a function is not used common enough to be included in a popular library. For high values of "popular", at least :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to [softwarerecs.SE] rather than here

Comment: I don't believe there are libraries available for this option. You may have to write custom recursive function to achieve this.